# How can I choose between multiple implementors of a trait without trait objects in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a trait called `Dataset` which has a single method to retrieve the contents of a file by its name and an associated `Error` type. The trait is implemented for different filesystem structures, e.g. a `PathBuf` for directory-based access or a `ZipArchive` for access in a compressed zip archive. For testing purposes also exists an implementation for `HashMap`.

```rust
trait Dataset {
    type Error: Error + 'static;

    fn read(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<String, Self::Error>;
}
```

Now, I want to deduce depending on a given file name which implementation to use: A directory if the path is an directory, a zip archive if the extension is `.zip` or `.bzip`, etc. Consider a function `fn run(dataset: impl Dataset)` which operates on a dataset. Having the choosing-code inlined, everything works: (Using a `Option<PathBuf>` is just for this example, the real code looks at the properties of the given path as described above)

```rust
let optional = Some(PathBuf::from("/path/to/dataset/.txt"));
match optional.clone() {
    Some(dataset) => run(dataset)?,
    None => run(static_dataset())?,
}
```

However, I’d prefer to decouple the functionality of (1) “choose an implementor for `Dataset`” from the (2) “give the `Dataset` to the `run` function”. I hope to make this function more reusable (as not only the `run` function could make use of (1)) and be more independend on changes of `run` – consider changes to the signature like adding more parameters.

I tried two approaches:

1. #### Trait objects

   While I’m not quite happy to use trait objects just for reasons of decoupling, I wouldn’t refuse this option ideologically.

   ```rust
   fn with_trait_object(optional: Option<PathBuf>) -> Box<dyn Dataset> {
       match optional {
           Some(dataset) => Box::new(dataset),
           None => Box::new(static_dataset),
       }
   }
   ```

   But this is rejected with the error message:

   ```
     error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Error` (from trait `Dataset`) must be specified
     --> src/main.rs:68:60
      |
   9  |     type Error: Error + 'static;
      |     ---------------------------- `Error` defined here
   ...
   68 | fn with_trait_object(optional: Option<PathBuf>) -> Box<dyn Dataset> {
      |
   ```

   It makes sense to me, as the `Dataset::Error` type is in a return position and we don’t know the exact size of it when using a trait object.
2. #### Closure as parameter

   My second approach is what I would prefer regarding its idea: Instead of returning a `Dataset` to my caller, the caller gives me a closure which will accept the `Dataset`. Then, the closure can be used to pass additional arguments to the actual processing function. I could also use different closures so I could reuse my “choose the correct implementor” functionality with ease.
   However, I can’t express “this function takes a closure `FnOnce` which is itself generic over the `Dataset` trait in its first parameter”. At the moment, I use `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` as return type for the closure, but it would be nice to be generic there, too. Here the erroneous code:

   ```rust
   fn with_consumer_function(
       optional: Option<PathBuf>,
       consumer: impl FnOnce(impl Dataset) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>,
   ) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
       match optional {
           Some(dataset) => consumer(dataset),
           None => consumer(static_dataset),
       }
   }
   ```

I am quite curious that it looks like I can’t factor out this piece of code as I can’t describe the correct signature of a consumer function. Is there a different way to order the type parameters? Or is there an entirely different approach possible?

A small example can be found on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b28641d060d5c894790aad8960960a2b).

Comment: *without trait objects* / *I wouldn’t refuse [trait objects] ideologically*. It's not clear how to answer your question when you place a requirement ("without") and then say "don't worry about the requirement".

Comment: @Shepmaster, the reason for the requirement in the title was that I would be fine with using trait objects in general, but in my concrete case, trait objects are not working. If you have a different phrasing for it, I’ll be happy to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start out with this:

```
fn with_consumer_function<DS: Dataset>(
    optional: Option<DS>,
    consumer: impl FnOnce(DS) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    match optional {
        Some(dataset) => consumer(dataset),
        None => todo!(), //consumer(static_dataset()),
    }
}
```

If you want to change the `None` arm, you would have to create a (generic) method to generate a dataset. You could do so by extending the trait `Dataset` with a `fn static_dataset() -> Self`.

The reason the `None` does not work with a closure is that rust (at least as of now) treats closures as accepting fixed parameters. If `consumer` accepts a `DS` in the first branch, it cannot simply accept `HashMap` in the second - it still must accept the same type: `DS`.

You could work around this by defining your own trait:

```
trait DatasetConsumer {
    fn call<DS: Dataset>(self, ds: DS) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
}

struct DatasetConsumerRun;
impl DatasetConsumer for DatasetConsumerRun {
    fn call<DS: Dataset>(self, mut dataset: DS) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        println!("{}", dataset.read("info.txt")?);
        Ok(())
    }
}
    
fn with_consumer_function<DS: Dataset>(
    optional: Option<DS>,
    consumer: impl DatasetConsumer,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    match optional {
        Some(dataset) => consumer.call(dataset),
        None => consumer.call(static_dataset()),
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let optional = Some(PathBuf::from("/path/to/dataset/.txt"));
    with_consumer_function(optional.clone(), DatasetConsumerRun)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

That said, it is more cumbersome to use `DatasetConsumer` than to use plain closures.

You could also try to implement `with_consumer_function` as a macro, but I'm not sure I would follow this path.

Answer (score 0):

Also I had a bash at wrestling the compiler into accepting. Here is the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f78cb2a5063a0cb231179348c825d8b2)

In but I think @phimuemue has has a pretty succinct response. In my case I added an enum for convenience instead of an associated type. And simply within the code avoided the generic by mapping a running closure over the `Option`. I am not sure if it fits the criterion of factoring out the match arm, but it feels convenient and avoids dynamic dispatch.

Comment: I like that you point out that using a `enum` instead of an associated type would enable to use this trait more flexibly. But, in your approach I can not see how I can swap in another consumer function – they are in the real code a lot more complex than the simple `consumer` I have shown in the example